# How to serialize and deserialize SURF descriptor in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working around SURF using OpenCV.
I want to put the SURF descriptor into cache, so I have to serialize the descriptor and then deserialize it back to descriptor.

What I did is as follows:

```
[serialize]
    kp, des = surf.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    jm = json.dumps(des.tolist())

[deserialize]
    du = json.loads(jm)
    dn = np.asarray(du)
```

I printed the type of `des`, `dn`, which both are type of `np.ndarray`.
Howerver, after the deserialization, I can't use the `dn` to perform the `knnMatch`, while using the original `des` is ok.

There is an error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescType) in knnMatchImpl, file /home/zibo/opencv/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp, line 722

It seems that, the original descriptor `des` is not just an type of `numpy.ndarray`. I searched the OpenCV codes but don't find the answer yet.

So, can anyone help. How to serialize and deserialize SURF descriptor?

Comment: Have you checked the `dtype` of the `ndarray`? Probably loading from json defaults to `float64`, or anyway something different from the original. Also, are you sure that serializing to json and back is actually good for performance? I highly doubt so.

Comment: yes, I have fixed the problem. It is the data type of float64 caused the problem. Thanks @Miki

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the loaded data to array, set data type to float32.

```
dn = np.asarray(du, dtype = np.float32)
```

I assume that 'np' here is the alias of 'numpy'.